# Exchange 2010 DR Site Setup

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

Currently i run a single site with 
1 Cas/Hub Server (no CAS Array)
2 Mailbox DB Servers

i'm in the process of setting up a DR Site and was planning on running
1 CAS/Hub Server
1 Mailbox Server (running DAG w/ both Primary Site MBX Servers).

is there anything special that needs to be configured for this setup to work.. who will users know what CAS to Connect to? is that managed by AD Sites and Servers?

anyone know of any good links that go over such a setup and how to make fail over seamless?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a simliar setup, except in a failover scenario, I would restore the CAS server that I've replicated via backup (Veeam) to the DR.  The 3 mailbox servers are in sync with DAG.

Comment: why are you replicating the cas instead of running an active one?

Comment: There is a way to configure a CAS "array", but my understanding is that they would both be active.  I don't want traffic going to the DR.